# Marginal densities (or bar plots) on facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

my problem is the following: I have this table below

```
        0   1-5  6-10 11-15 16-20 21-26 27-29
  a 0.019 0.300 0.296 0.211 0.117 0.042 0.014
  b 0.058 0.448 0.308 0.120 0.042 0.019 0.005
  c 0.026 0.277 0.316 0.187 0.105 0.068 0.020
  d 0.054 0.297 0.378 0.108 0.108 0.041 0.014
  e 0.004 0.252 0.358 0.216 0.102 0.053 0.015
  f 0.032 0.097 0.312 0.280 0.161 0.065 0.054
  g 0.113 0.500 0.233 0.094 0.043 0.014 0.003
  h 0.328 0.460 0.129 0.050 0.020 0.010 0.003
```

representing some marginal frequencies (by row) for each subgroups of my data (a to h).

My dataset is actually in the long format (**very** long, counting more than 100 thousand entries), with the first 6 rows as you see below:

```
                RX_SUMM_SURG_PRIM_SITE Nodes.Examined.Class
1                      Wedge Resection                  1-5
2                  Segmental Resection                  1-5
3 Lobectomy w/mediastinal LNdissection                 6-10
4 Lobectomy w/mediastinal LNdissection                 6-10
5 Lobectomy w/mediastinal LNdissection                  1-5
6 Lobectomy w/mediastinal LNdissection                11-15
```

When I plot a barplot by group (the table above is simply the cross tabulation of of these two covariates with the row marginal probabilities taken) here's what happens:

[image]

The code I have for this is

```
ggplot(data.ln.red, aes(x=Nodes.Examined.Class))+geom_bar(aes(x=Nodes.Examined.Class, group=RX_SUMM_SURG_PRIM_SITE))+
  facet_grid(RX_SUMM_SURG_PRIM_SITE~.)
```

Actually I would be very happy only with the **marginal frequencies** (i.e. the ones in the table) on each y-axis of the facets of the plot (instead of the counts).

Anybody can help me with this?

Thanks for all your help!
EM

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what do you want it to look like? Keep in mind that `ggplot` generally expects long-shaped data, not wide, so maybe start by getting it into that shape

Comment: Thanks Camille, I have edited my request in a hopefully clearer version.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_bar` calculates both counts and proportions of observations. You can access these calculated proportions with either `..prop..` (the old way) or `calc(prop)` (introduced in newer versions of `ggplot2`). Use this as your y aesthetic.

You can also get rid of the `aes` you have in `geom_bar`, as this is just a repeat of what you've already covered by `ggplot` and `facet_grid`.

It looks like your counts/proportions are going to vary widely between groups, so I'm adding free y-scaling to the faceting.

Here's an example of a similar plot with the iris data, which you can model your code off of:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = calc(prop))) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    facet_grid(Species ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

**Edit:** the calculated `prop` variable is proportions *within each* group, not proportions *across all* groups, so it works differently when x is a factor. For categorical x, `prop` treats x as the group; to override this, include `group = 0` or some other dummy value in your `aes`. Sorry I missed that the first time!